# Android developer newbie unable to launch code in the emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, twitter, android-emulator

Background:

I have started Android recently. I want to make an application for Android that fetches data from a server and customizes it , displays it and then use Twitter to tweet the results. I am thinking to use (twitter4j API for this.).

Initially i have a PERL file on server that i need to call from my application's interface. (I have modified code of HelloWorld.java available at (dev.android..). The PERL file which i have stored on the server has the output in form of **print ""** I would be using the collective print output and decode them in my application.

Now my code is as follows :

```
package com.example.helloandroid;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloWorldAndroidActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView tv=new TextView(this);
        /*      tv.setText("Hello, World !! This is my First Android App .. Cheers");
        setContentView(tv);*/

        try {
            InputStream is = new URL("http://myserver.com:1941/cgi-bin/myperl.pl").openStream();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String str = in.readLine();
            in.close();
            tv.setText(str);
            setContentView("phew");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            //FAIL
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //FAIL
        }


    }
}
```

However i am not able to use the code to get the data from the server file as Eclipse emulator shows up but does not displays anything except the "shinny android logo".

Is there any way i can read that file? Also i would like you seniors to suggest me some startup/dummies book fro Android development.

Comment: Wait more, until emulator assignes all the resources and creates an environment, then you will se a normal home screen on the emulator. shining logo means it is still loading. If yourcomputer is fast enough, then loading will not take long time, but if it is not, then it could be a problem.. with my netbook i've been waiting hours sometimes =)

Comment: Now emulator says: system not responding... getting weird.. and yes i am using C2D 2.4Ghz, Gen. Win7 Ultimate x64 with 4Gigs of RAM...

Comment: try reinstalling or look into the task manager and make sure that there are no viruses that are using your cpu. By the way, on Unix i had a chance to make sure that process load is distributed among all the cpus, but this is the last thing you should consider doing.. Load emulator again and watch in task manager how much memory is used by the "emulator" process. I had mine around 150K K, then it shows the home screen, usually i got ine stuck on like 149 and no more progress, and then after some time it started from the beginning

Comment: @hatesms you want me to use the gdblog? It is present is %sysdrive%\eclipse\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools but .. invoking it in eclipse Galilleo, still searching...

Comment: @MocialovBoris Sire.. i am using Genuine Windows 7 using MSE. there are no viruses at all on my machine. Emulator is taking 138 MB...

Comment: People... have you forgotten the thread??

Comment: I noticed in the code that you called `setContentView("phew")`. Unless I am missing something, this code will not even compile since you need to pass either a View or resource id. The emulator not booting up properly seems to be a different issue though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long do you want for the emulator to boot up? It can take upwards of two minutes to boot up. It's kind of slow in that respect. Try giving it a little time to actually get to the home screen. Also, is your [logcat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html) saying anything interesting?

Also, you're doing a network operation on the main UI thread. NEVER do this. You need to move your network operations on to a different thread. For more details, read [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

Comment: Emulator works if i remove inputstream's display. So i think i am doing some wrong over there. And yes the Emulator is pretty bad.. 2 minutes (what were they thinking.. ??) 

Yes i will use the painless threading tip in mind.. i just want to startup and write code..thinking to optimize it once i am done finishing smaller tasks..